# SQL - default columns

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.t_id = table2.t_id
UNION
SELECT table1.col1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.col4 = null
```

Problem is, I this syntax is invalid because the 2nd statement doesn't include the same # of columns as the 1st statement.

I can't include table2.col2 in the second statement because I don't need it.

Is there anyway for me to include a default second column in the 2nd statement so that I can get this query to work?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just use a constant such as 1 or ''.

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.t_id = table2.t_id
UNION
SELECT table1.col1, '' as col2 FROM table1 WHERE table1.col4 = null
```

Comment: @Joel - true, but I didn't know what he wanted in the column.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? You don't have to pull values out of the table... you can always create them out of thin air. :)

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.t_id = table2.t_id
UNION
SELECT table1.col1, 'whatever' FROM table1 WHERE table1.col4 is null
```

Answer (score 3):

I typically use `NULL` (which should coerce into any type):

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.t_id = table2.t_id
UNION
SELECT table1.col1, NULL AS col2 FROM table1 WHERE table1.col4 = null
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to use null for the dummy column, so it'll work more like an outer join (unless you have a specific need that the column have a particular value).

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 
    FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.t_id = table2.t_id
UNION
SELECT table1.col1, null 
    FROM table1 WHERE table1.col4 = null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use empty ('') quotes in your column list for columns you don't want in the second SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a union or union all the number of columns must match.  You'll need to either hard code a value to put in that column, or query the sys.columns catalog view and get the default value for the column you are inserting into, and use that value there.